# "npm install -g yo generator-code" gives wierd errors

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-install

I open VS Code, and them I show the terminal and it opens up Powershell, so far so good. The application is also started as Administrator. Then I type in:

```
npm install -g yo generator-code
```

But it fails. I am unsure what, this is the first time I'm using npm, but it doesn't work, I know that much. When i try yo code, it says that yo is not recognized.
The above command outputs the following "errors":

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 869 packages, and audited 870 packages in 1m

59 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

15 vulnerabilities (13 moderate, 2 high)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
```

I saw multiple tutorials on installing this, and none of them detailed what to do if it fails like this. But I assumed i should run npm audit fix. But when running that command it gives the following output:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-02-06T21_40_42_240Z-debug.log
```

And in case it helps, here is the contents of the debug.log file mentioned in the output above:

```
0 verbose cli [
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
0 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
0 verbose cli   'audit',
0 verbose cli   'fix'
0 verbose cli ]
1 info using npm@8.1.2
2 info using node@v16.13.2
3 timing npm:load:whichnode Completed in 0ms
4 timing config:load:defaults Completed in 2ms
5 timing config:load:file:C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\npmrc Completed in 4ms
6 timing config:load:builtin Completed in 4ms
7 timing config:load:cli Completed in 3ms
8 timing config:load:env Completed in 1ms
9 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\jevar\documents\github\.npmrc Completed in 1ms
10 timing config:load:project Completed in 3ms
11 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\jevar\.npmrc Completed in 0ms
12 timing config:load:user Completed in 0ms
13 timing config:load:file:C:\Users\jevar\AppData\Roaming\npm\etc\npmrc Completed in 1ms
14 timing config:load:global Completed in 1ms
15 timing config:load:validate Completed in 0ms
16 timing config:load:credentials Completed in 1ms
17 timing config:load:setEnvs Completed in 2ms
18 timing config:load Completed in 17ms
19 timing npm:load:configload Completed in 18ms
20 timing npm:load:setTitle Completed in 0ms
21 timing npm:load:setupLog Completed in 0ms
22 timing config:load:flatten Completed in 5ms
23 timing npm:load:cleanupLog Completed in 5ms
24 timing npm:load:configScope Completed in 0ms
25 timing npm:load:projectScope Completed in 0ms
26 timing npm:load Completed in 31ms
27 timing arborist:ctor Completed in 0ms
28 timing command:audit Completed in 6ms
29 verbose stack Error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file
29 verbose stack     at Arborist.loadVirtual (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\load-virtual.js:62:18)
29 verbose stack     at async Arborist.audit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\@npmcli\arborist\lib\arborist\audit.js:25:18)
29 verbose stack     at async Audit.audit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\audit.js:66:5)
30 verbose cwd C:\Users\jevar\documents\github
31 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.19044
32 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "audit" "fix"
33 verbose node v16.13.2
34 verbose npm  v8.1.2
35 error code ENOLOCK
36 error audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
37 error audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
38 error audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file
39 verbose exit 1
```

As I said, this is my first time using npm so I have no idea what this is, or what to do. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I didn't generate the package-lock.json file.
Did you try running the command it says there?

```
npm i --package-lock-only
```

Then if it keeps throwing an error, execute the following command:

```
npm audit fix
```

If all of that doesn't work, I would recommend you to share the project structure to check the package-lock.json file

I hope I have helped